# Removing stopwords from a large corpus in RStudio

Tags: r, stop-words

I am trying to clean some text from a large corpus and have problems removing stopwords. When I run the code `myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("en"))` the small Stop Sign in the console keeps running and never gives me a result. I have tried to let it run for many hours but it still gives me no result.

I tried to both restart my R and run the code on a smaller corpus, but it keeps giving me no results. Have any of you experience this before and now how to get the code to work?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(c(Delta_2,British_2,American_2)))

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, stopwords("en"))
```

Comment: what is format(object.size(myCorpus), 'Mb')?

Comment: stop word removal is eminently parallelizable, have you tried this?

Comment: It was a CSV file that I converted into a corpus, if that was what you were asking for. I am new in R :)